# Simple choice function does not seem to work (C++)

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, fstream

I have been working on an exercise in my c++ programming book and it basically is asking me to create a program that will take 3 files, an old master file of client data (account, name, balance), a transaction file (of account names and credits or debits), and then a function to merge this files and output a new master file of client data. I am pretty sure I know how to do this, or even if I don't I think I can figure it out, the problem I am having is with a simple choice selection interface which is implemented exactly the same as another program that works just fine. When I first run the program it will let me input a choice (int) and then run the appropriate function (of which I only have 1 implemented completely, that being the createMasterFile function. After creating entries in the file and having them read back to the screen just for debugging and verification purposees, it will return to the while statement below but if I watch the choice function in both the main function and the enterChoice() function when I make the first selection (the one that works) those variables (according to gdb) do not take on any values until AFTER createMasterFile runs, before that it states that it is not in scope, after it runs through once choice will take on the original value 1 as it hits while, then seems to skip the condition of the while statement, then hits the switch statement which somehow changes choice to 0 which then hits the default case which then returns to the while statement and choice takes on a value of 32767 and again seems to skip the conditional part of the while statement and gets stuck in an infinite loop at this point with choice never changing in value. In a very similar program (the only difference is that the program that works uses binary files instead of sequential files) this works just fine. The interface looks like this:

```
enum Choices {CREATE_MASTER =1, CREATE_TRANSACTION, SORT_MASTER, UPDATE_MASTER, SORT_TRANS, UPDATE_TRANS, MERGE, END  };

int choice;

while ( ( choice = enterChoice()) != END )
{
    switch( choice )
    {
        case CREATE_MASTER:
            createMasterFile( inOutOldMasterFile );
            break;
        case CREATE_TRANSACTION:
            break;
        case SORT_MASTER:
            break;
        case UPDATE_MASTER:
            break;
        case SORT_TRANS:
            break;
        case UPDATE_TRANS:
            break;
        case MERGE:
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Incorrect choice" << endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

and the enterchoice() function is:

```
int enterChoice()
{
cout << "\nEnter your choice below" << endl
    << "1 - Create Master Record" << endl
    << "2 - Create Transaction Record" << endl
    << "3 - Sort Master File In Descending Order" << endl
    << "4 - Update Master File" << endl
    << "5 - Sort Transaction File" << endl
    << "6 - Update Transaction File" << endl
    << "7 - Merge Transaction and Old Master File" << endl
    << "8 - End Program\n?";

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}
```

If you need to see all the code (just for clarity) here it is (for the functions that are currently being used)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void outputLine( int, const string, double );
void createMasterFile( fstream & );
int numberOfAccounts = 0;
void swap(int * const, int * const);
void swap( string * const, string * const);
void swap( double * const, double * const);
bool descending( int, int);
void sortAccounts(int, fstream &, bool (*)(int, int));
int enterChoice();

int main()
{
// create a fstream object for input and output to be passed to
// the functions that need to manipulate it.
fstream inOutOldMasterFile( "oldmaster.dat", ios::in | ios::out );
fstream inOutTransaction( "trans.dat", ios::in | ios::out );
ofstream outNewMaster( "newmaster.dat", ios::out);

enum Choices {CREATE_MASTER =1, CREATE_TRANSACTION, SORT_MASTER, UPDATE_MASTER, SORT_TRANS, UPDATE_TRANS, MERGE, END  };

int choice;

while ( ( choice = enterChoice()) != END )
{
    switch( choice )
    {
        case CREATE_MASTER:
            createMasterFile( inOutOldMasterFile );
            break;
        case CREATE_TRANSACTION:
            break;
        case SORT_MASTER:
            break;
        case UPDATE_MASTER:
            break;
        case SORT_TRANS:
            break;
        case UPDATE_TRANS:
            break;
        case MERGE:
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Incorrect choice" << endl;
            break;
    }
}
return 0;
}

int enterChoice()
{
cout << "\nEnter your choice below" << endl
    << "1 - Create Master Record" << endl
    << "2 - Create Transaction Record" << endl
    << "3 - Sort Master File In Descending Order" << endl
    << "4 - Update Master File" << endl
    << "5 - Sort Transaction File" << endl
    << "6 - Update Transaction File" << endl
    << "7 - Merge Transaction and Old Master File" << endl
    << "8 - End Program\n?";

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

void createMasterFile( fstream &clientFile )
{
if(!clientFile)
{
    clientFile.open("oldmaster.dat", ios::in | ios::out);
}

cout << "Enter the account, name and balance." << endl
    << "Enter end-of-file to end input (^d)\n? ";

int account;
string name;
double balance;

clientFile.seekp( 0, ios::beg );

// read account, name and balance from cin then place in file
while (cin >> account >> name >> balance )
{
    numberOfAccounts++;
    clientFile << account << ' ' << name << ' ' << balance << endl;

    cout << "?";
} //end while

clientFile.seekg( 0, ios::beg );

cout << left << setw(10) << "Account" << setw(13)
    << "Name" << "Balance" << endl << fixed << showpoint;

while( clientFile >> account >> name >> balance)
{
    outputLine( account, name, balance );
}

clientFile.close();
}
```

If this is really obvious I am sorry but I have tried to find some answer for almost 2 days now searching online.

Thanks in advance.

-Bobby

Comment: You might want to check that `cin >> choice` for success on subsequent loops.

Comment: Your `createMasterFile` function is reading all of the input from `cin`.  There is none left for another choice.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow the second comment here, you're saying that the `while (cin >> account >> name >> balance)` portion of `createMasterFile` is somehow stopping `cin >> choice` in `enterChoice()`?  If so I don't see how, should I use `getline` or some other input method or how am I going about this wrong?

Comment: @user2691098: Having some other way of representing the end of input rather than using the end-of-file would be one option.  Clearing the eof state from the stream as Dietmar suggested is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `createMasterFile()` reads from `std::cin` until `std::cin` goes into failure mode, e.g., because a wrong value was encountered or `std::cin` reached its end. This function correctly checks the input after reading.

After that, your `enterChoice()` function is entered without first clearing the failure setting for `std::cin` and this function doesn't check whether the read is actually successful and it won't because the stream is already in failure mode. The function should probably read the value and return a result something like this:

```
std::cin >> choice;
return std::cin? choice: ERROR;
```

Since `createMasterFile()` clearly leaves `std::cin` in failure mode, you should probably reset its state before trying to read your choice and probably also ignore the rest of the current line:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Of course, if there is no further input from `std::cin`, reading a choice will still fail.

Comment: ahh ok i think I got what you're saying here. Got to eat dinner now but I'll try fixing it sortly with your recommendations. In 17 chapters I don't recall ever being told about `cin.clear()` or `cin.ignore( ....)` 

Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2691098: Sadly, I'm not surprised. There are few people who understand IOStreams and even fewer capable of writing about it. I think Nicolai Josuttis "The C++ Standard Library" at least mentions these functions (if not, I'm to blame as I translated/wrote parts of the IOStreams chapter; Nicolai brushed my writing up to become readable, though).

Comment: well its no problem, I am having trouble with the cin.ignore function, I'm using code::blocks IDE btw, I have `using namespace std` declared and when i start to type `numberic_limits` it comes up in the list as C++ but when compiling it states its not declared in this scope, so I add `std::` to it and then the compiler states its not in namespace std, ill look it up but I am just letting you know that this is what its telling me....

Comment: @user2691098: The class template `std::numeric_limits` is declared and specialized for the built-in types in the header `<limits>`. You probably need to include this header.

Comment: ahh, I was using `<climits>` which is evidently only the integral types like `char` `int` `double` etc... Now it works perfectly! At least what I have written so far. THANKS! 

One other question though, you say that my `createMasterFile()` function correctly checks the input, I don't see any validation checks, could you expand on what you meant by that?

Otherwise thank you for your help here, its much appreciated.

Comment: @user2691098: Well, you use something like `while (cin >> account >> name >> balance)` which tries to read three values from `std::cin` and checks whether that was successful: if any of the input attempts fails, `std::cin` is set into failure mode and converting the stream to a Boolean value yields `false`. If all went OK the conversion to Boolean yields `true`.

Comment: alright, i got you, thanks very much for all the help and patience explaining this, hopefully I hopefully wont be preforming this error again.